# Reading with BinaryReader will not update TextBox

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, textbox, binaryreader

I wrote this code and I think there is an easier way to do it that may work, but I just don't know how. I tried changing the code for about 3 hours and I'm getting no where. The `TextBox` won't update when I'm reading a byte that would convert it to a string; it only works if I put only one `If` statement with the correct byte that translates it into a string. I'm doing this for a couple of other addresses in the file and I also shortened the code to put up on here as an example of what I'm trying to do. Hope you guys can help me out.

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim fileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim fileStream As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(fileName, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fileStream)
    fileStream.Position = 2348
    If br.ReadByte = 76 Then
        TextBox1.Text += " "
    ElseIf br.ReadByte = 175 Then
        TextBox1.Text += "."
    ElseIf br.ReadByte = 186 Then
        TextBox1.Text += "A"
    End If
    fileStream.Close()
    br.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: **Hint:** When you call `br.ReadByte` the current position (which is 2348 in your case) advances by one byte. So after the first `If..` the position is 2349, and after the first `ElseIf` its `2350` and after the last check its `2351`. So, think about it.

Comment: Also you should dispose `fileStream` and `br`. Create them in `Using..End Using` block instead.

Comment: I've confirmed that advancing one byte isn't true, it reads okay. 'Cause I edited which in case is a game save using a program that searches values. It wouldn't read correctly only when I put elseifs and I tried using the Using and End Using block and it still didn't work. I did something similar with a Combo box getting selected to a certain index; It works perfectly fine. But there's probably something wrong with using ".text" I tried it on a label and it still wouldn't work. I'm stumped.

Comment: Read [BinaryReader.ReadByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbyte?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_BinaryReader_ReadByte)

Comment: After `fileStream.Position = 2348`, get the current byte in a variable: `Dim b = br.ReadByte` then do the `If.ElseIf...` using the `b` variable.

Comment: That didn't work either, but thanks for the help.

Comment: I fixed it, I just had to keep calling the position right before multiple If; End Ifs and read the byte one by one with the different values. That Microsoft site you linked me gave me that clue. Thanks a lot!